# SHOW formatted JSON in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

There is one json object in .JS file of LWC component.

```js
@track 
jsonVariable = {"type":"Payments","filter":{"currencies":[]}, "clientCode":230};
```

We want to render json data on HTML page.Like below,

[image]

JSON should be rendered in proper/ beautified manner.
How to achieve this in LWC ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? Or at least, show us the URL you got the screenshot from so we can copy it for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below answer.It is working. We just have to make some changes as per LWC.
For example,
Instead of document.getElementById("json") use template.querySelector().

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862627/json-stringify-output-to-div-in-pretty-print-way

Comment: Could you please add the contents of the link to your answer and what exactly you did to make it work?